# docker exec - sh: can't open 'script.sh': No such file or directory

Tags: docker, dockerfile

i am trying to run a script from my docker container using `docker exec`

here is my dockerfile

```
FROM docker.odyssey.rowini.net/traefik:2.10.1
COPY traefik.toml /traefik.toml
COPY middleware.toml /config/middleware.toml
COPY tls.toml /config/tls.toml
EXPOSE 33233 22322 8080 8082
ENV ENVIRONMENT=""
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "script.sh"]
```

script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

find /path/to/folder -type f -name "*.toml" -exec sed -i -e "s/ENV/${ENVIRONMENT}/g" {} +
```

and these are the commands that i have ran

```
docker build -f Dockerfile --tag container1 .
docker run -it --rm --name container1
docker exec container1 sh script.sh
```

but i ran into the following error
`sh: can't open 'load_env.sh': No such file or directory`

the dockerfile and script.sh are in the same directory, so i am not sure why it is not able to read the file

Comment: You seem to be missing a `COPY` command for `script.sh`

Comment: (You probably shouldn't need `docker exec` in routine use; do you need to run this script in a different way?)